# How to create & code a function which is used ONLY once - EVER! .... at first Start Up

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm looking for some code where 'How to create & code a function which is used ONLY once - EVER! .... at first Start Up of AIR App.??? this I need to download the first set v1.0 of Xml base data files in an AIR Application and after that this particular function should never EVER be addressed again!
Any help would be appreciated regards aktell

Answer (score 0):

a) write a function on init or CreationComplete event.
b) write an object extending objectproxy, introduce a flag, and allow it to use only if the flag is default, and then set the flag to other value.
c) write a static function with a static counter, and when you call it, check if counter != 0,  to return, and counter++;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use "SharedObject" in this case, so you can set a flag.
On each run the flag will be checked, if true or false you can trigger a function to execute.

[Flex Mobile Development: storing data locally](http://corlan.org/2011/08/18/flex-mobile-development-storing-data-locally/)

you also can encrypt the stored data

[Flex Mobile Development – Encrypting Data](http://devgirl.org/2011/09/22/flex-mobile-development-encrypting-data/)

Hope this will workout for you...

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, use the PersistenceManager to store a flag after first time run , 
for more info about PersistenceManager http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/managers/PersistenceManager.html